# Server manager, Internet information Services, Credential Service Bridge

Tags: service, credentials, windows-server, bridge, servermanager

I'm trying to create a Credential Service Bridge on a windows Machine, each time i try to Add Roles and Features through Server Manager i get this message shown below. [image]